# Tracking conversions from another property

Tags: google-analytics

I have one website and 2 blogs. Everything is working for years and till recently we were ok with setup.
I am promoting one of the blog pages on Twitter,Facebook,LinkedIn. I can see conversions on main property but I cant tell how many conversions were from each of the sources. I just can see blog page as a source. When i switch to blog property in GA i can see segmented traffic by sources but ofc no conversions (goals are defined only on the main site)

I am reading for tracking goals from multiple properties but it only confuses me more and more. Is this possible to pass data from one property to another and be able to see what I want to see (segmentation by sources and conversions) ?

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Google Analytics, and when I walked through the setup process, there was a lot of explanation about Social settings. I suspect this is new. Google has put in fields for you to track traffic to your blogs that comes in from your other social presence(s).

You'll want to identify your profile URLs for Twitter, LinkedIn and Facebook so that it can break it down for you correctly.

They state:

> If you leave the Web Property Prefix blank, you'll see Activities data for the domain you are tracking with Google Analytics (e.g. example.com). If you also wish to see Activities data for properties such as your YouTube channel, enter your prefixes here; for example, youtube.com/example. **Make your prefix as specific as possible (i.e. do not simply enter youtube.com)**. Activities data is only shown for properties from which your domain has received hits.

**Source**: [Google Analytics Social Settings: Web Property Prefix Help](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2464956?hl=en)